# How to Arrange a property of the base class using JustMockLite

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, justmock

I am using the free version of JustMock for writing the unit tests. I have am CustomApiController class which inherits system.web.Http.ApiController class. So from `system.web.Http.ApiController` class comes a property called Request (which is of `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` type. Now in the method for which I am writing my unit test has something like:

```
if (this.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("HeaderName", out someCollectionOfStrings)
```

How can I arrange/mock the Request object to return this as true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by creating a new request object and assigned it to our controller request property.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://stackoverflow");
            request.Headers.Add("HeaderName","3443");
_apiController.Request = request;
```